# Is Einstein STO activity in journey builder considered a "wait activity" for the purposes of Exit Criteria?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, einstein

Given that the Einstein STO activity must be immediately followed by an Email activity, I'm wondering how this works with Exit Criteria?

Documentation for Exit Criteria says "Journey Builder evaluates exit criteria for each contact in the journey when their time in each wait activity expires."

Is the Einstein STO activity considered to be a "wait activity"? specifically, will a contact that is waiting in the STO that then meets exit criteria be exited before being sent the email that follows the STO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the Einstein STO activity is a modified wait activity, and so it inherits the same behavior. And yes, Exit and Goal Criteria are evaluated when the contacts come out of the Einstein STO activity, as with the Journey Builder Wait activity.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to run some tests and can confirm Exit Criteria works for Einstein STO activities.